# Iterate through list in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

1st year of CSE in HS. Coding a pizza order program. Teacher wants a separate function for computing cost. I am struggling with getting the program to add on the price of the toppings. Each pizza is $13 and toppings are extra. Goal is to have it charge for a plain pizza (empty list), pizza with toppings, or no pizza at all.

```
def pizza_cost(pizza):
  global total
  total += 13.00
  for y in pizza:
    if (y == "Pepperoni"):
      total += 1.00

order = input("Would you like to make an order? (y or n)")
while order != "n":
  pizza_order = input("Would you like a pizza? (y or n)")
  pizza = []
  while pizza_order.upper() != "N":
    if pizza_order.upper() == "Y":
      topping_option = input("Would you like to add a topping? (y or n)")
      while topping_option.upper() != "N":
        topping_list = []
        topping = input("What topping would you like? Pepperoni (p), Mushroom (m)")
        if topping.upper() == "P":
          topping_list.append("Pepperoni")
        elif topping.upper() == "M":
          topping_list.append("Mushroom")
        topping_option = input("Would you like to add another topping? (y or n)")
      pizza.append(topping_list)
    pizza_order = input("Would you like another pizza? (y or n)")
  for x in pizza:
    pizza_cost(pizza)
# Example order (Two plain pizzas and pizza with double-pepperoni)
([], [], ["Pepperoni", "Pepperoni"])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you have `total` as a `global`? Is this part of the requirements for the assignment?

I would think that `pizza_cost` would return the cost of the pizza, then you would sum that value in one of your loops

Comment: @Tomerikoo When I run the program, it adds the price for plain pizzas (Ex: $26 for two) but when I try to add toppings, it does not add the price for them.

Comment: Did you try to debug your program to find out where the problem is? Can you make this into a [mre] and ask a specific programming question?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code is that you are passing the list of pizza lists `pizza`, instead of a single pizza `x`, to the `pizza_cost` function, at the end of your code:

```py
  for x in pizza:
    pizza_cost(pizza)
```

If you pass `x` instead, your whole code will do what you want ;) !

```py
  for x in pizza:
    pizza_cost(x)
```